# How do I use scrollorama

Tags: html, css, superscrollorama

I've tried everything but I can't seem to get scrollorama to work with this and I'm not sure why. There is an error in the console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollorama is not defined"

JavaScript:

```
scrollorama.animate('.navigation',{
    delay:993, duration:993, property:'top', start:100, end:-300
});
```

Live demo:

http://matthunzinger.com/

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you look at [the example on GitHub](https://github.com/johnpolacek/scrollorama/blob/master/index.html), i.e. `$.scrollorama({ blocks:'.scrollblock' });`?

Comment: May be this will help
jQuery Scrollorama error.
  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958080/scrollorama-js-cannot-call-method-replace-of-undefined-error-or-a-differe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollorama is not defined`

The console is telling you your problem.  You have not defined `scrollorama`.

Define `scrollorama`, ex:

```
var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({
        blocks:'.scrollblock'
    });
```

It's not defined, as I see in the page with your JS: http://matthunzinger.com/js.js

All you have is

```
scrollorama.animate('.navigation',{
    delay:993, duration:993, property:'top', start:100, end:-300
});
```

Because you have a class called `slide`, I'm guessing you need to add this before your code:

```
var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({
        blocks:'.slide'
    });
```

### Hold on, wait

I suggest that before you go on, you *read* the [scrollorama main page (I got the answer from here)](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/)

Comment: that simply causes another error. By the way I apologize that i'm horrible with java

Comment: @user3195968 1. It's Javascript, 2. I said 'example', don't take it literal.  I don't know what you want with the page, I was just telling you the problem